# android database SQL query, bug and fixing

Tags: android

I'm trying to call the class from databaseHandler but i seeing the error message when starting run the emulator, "the application has stooped to open". Thank for help i'm a beginner.

On my Main class

```
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.examplepractise/com.example.examplepractise.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nameTEXT,phoneTEXT,emailTEXT,addressTEXT,imageUrlTEXT)
```

Below is my create table SQL, it is any problem?

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context){ 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_NAME +"TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + "TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURL + "TEXT)" );
    }
```

Comment: use `" TEXT,"` instead of `"TEXT,"`, and `AUTO INCREMENT` not `AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: after i make the changer, the error still same. It is execSQL i create wrong syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this line:

> CREATE TABLEcontacts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nameTEXT,phoneTEXT,emailTEXT,addressTEXT,imageUrlTEXT)

you forgot to add spaces. For example you are trying to create a column name nameTEXT. What is actually want is a a column name name with the type TEXT. Add a space between them. Same for TABLE and contacts, AUTO and INCREMENT, phone and TEXT, etc.

Comment: the error i saw is as below, it is the SQL is correct now ?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.examplepractise/com.example.examplepractise.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE contacts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,name TEXT,phone TEXT,email TEXT,address TEXT,imageUrl TEXT)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_NAME +" TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURL + " TEXT)" );
```

instead of

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_NAME +"TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + "TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURL + "TEXT)" );
```

As you can see, there are spaces added now.

Comment: the error i saw is as below, it is the SQL is correct now ?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.examplepractise/com.example.examplepractise.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE contacts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,name TEXT,phone TEXT,email TEXT,address TEXT,imageUrl TEXT)

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT has no space

Comment: (1) near "FROMcontacts": syntax error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.examplepractise/com.example.examplepractise.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMcontacts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMcontacts

Comment: Thank you very much teach me how to see the error , and i know what i'm wrong xD